# Can I delete /home/USER/bitcoin after successfully installing bitcoind?

Tags: bitcoind, installation

I wonder if I can delete the git folder I cloned after I did the installation. Probably yes, right? Do people do this? Or is it more usefull to update the git after some time and then build `bitcoind` again?